# Rails app deployed on Centos w/ standalone Passenger and Capistrano can't access ENV variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, capistrano, passenger, centos7

I set up a Centos 7 VM using this tutorial (standalone passenger) and RVM. I am deploying the rails app via Capistrano.

https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/ruby/ownserver/standalone/oss/install_language_runtime.html

Everything seems to work, except no matter where I set environment variables, the ENV["myvar"] can't be read in Rails.

I've tried `export myvar=test` SSHed as the "deployers" as well as root. I've also tried adding it to bashrc. If I login as deployer and do the following:

```
#symlink to current capistrano deploy
cd ~/rails/railsapp/current/
rails r "puts ENV['myvar']"
```

It gives me the correct ENV output. However, if I try to output ENV['myvar'] from my actual deployed via capistrano rails app, I get nothing.

Where am I supposed to set these ENV vars? I know the ENV vars in rails are done correctly, because the app deployed to heroku, as well as on my dev machine, correctly output ENV['myvar'].

Comment: do you have `myvar.rb` under `config/deploy`

Comment: No under that directory is just production.rb. What would that file accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, your setup should work. Since version 4, a standalone Passenger should inherit all variables defined in the shell startup scripts. There is a nice [documentation about environment variables](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/indepth/environment_variables.html) in various scenarios related to using Passenger.

I would check or two things:

- That your `.bashrc` is loaded from `.profile`. If it weren't, then your variables would be loaded only in an interactive shell but not in passenger, which would explain the behavior your describe when you tried to log in as the `deployers`. Let me quote from the doc:

  > Make sure your `~/.bashrc` is actually included by your `~/.profile`, which might not be the case if you created the user with `useradd` instead of `adduser` for example.
- Also, take a look at [this section](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/indepth/environment_variables.html#passenger-served-apps) of the docs and check that you obey the conditions upon which Passenger actually passes the environment vars to the application.